# Efficient way to read/write/parse large text files (python)

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Say I have an absurdly large text file. I would not think my file would grow larger than ~500mb, but for the sake of scalability and my own curiosity, let's say it is on the order of a few gig.

My end goal is to map it to an array of sentences (separated by '?' '!' '.' and for all intents and purposes ';') and each sentence to an array of words. I was then going to use numpy for some statistical analysis.

What would be the most scalable way to go about doing this?

PS: I thought of rewriting the file to have one sentence per line, but I ran into problems trying to load the file into memory. I know of the solution where you read off chucks of data in one file, manipulate them, and write them to another, but that seems inefficient with disk memory. I know, most people would not worry about using 10gig of scratch space nowadays, but it does seem like there ought to be a way of directly editing chucks of the file.

Comment: *for all intensive purposes* or *for all intents and purposes*?

Comment: why not use a database, like sqllite?

Comment: Why don't you just scan the file as a stream and keep counts instead? It is not like the parsing would be complicated, would it?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know how to use sqllite. I am however decent with python.

Comment: Do you really need the sentence separation, or just the word separation?

Comment: Actually, yes, I do need sentence separation. The project I am working on involves determining statistical causal relationships between words. So I want to keep track of things like the probability the word "gem" will be the word following "ruby." Obviously, there will be a much less meaningful relationship between a word at the end of one sentence and the beginning of the next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought would be to use a stream parser: basically you read in the file a piece at a time and do the statistical analysis as you go. This is typically done with markup languages like HTML and XML, so you'll find a lot of parsers for those languages out there, including in the Python standard library. A simple sentence parser is something you can write yourself, though; for example:

```
import re, collections
sentence_terminator = re.compile(r'(?<=[.!?;])\s*')
class SentenceParser(object):
    def __init__(self, filelike):
        self.f = filelike
        self.buffer = collections.deque([''])
    def next(self):
        while len(self.buffer) < 2:
            data = self.f.read(512)
            if not data:
                raise StopIteration()
            self.buffer += sentence_terminator.split(self.buffer.pop() + data)
        return self.buffer.popleft()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

This will only read data from the file as needed to complete a sentence. It reads in 512-byte blocks so you'll be holding less than a kilobyte of file contents in memory at any one time, no matter how large the actual file is.

After a stream parser, my second thought would be to [memory map](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) the file. That way you could go through and replace the space that (presumably) follows each sentence terminator by a newline; after that, each sentence would start on a new line, and you'd be able to open the file and use `readline()` or a `for` loop to go through it line by line. But you'd still have to worry about multi-line sentences; plus, if any sentence terminator is *not* followed by a whitespace character, you would have to insert a newline (instead of replacing something else with it) and that could be horribly inefficient for a large file.